# Ignore missing columns when restoring a SQL dump

Tags: postgresql, psql, postgresql-9.5, pg-dump

I want to import a database dump into a new database that does not have all columns that the old database had.

How can I ignore these columns?

Dump created:

```
pg_dump --data-only old_database > dump_data_12_3_2019.sql;
```

When I try to import the dump, I got the following error:

```
psql:sdump.sql:3569: ERROR:  column "column" of relation "table" does not exist
```

Comment: Aside from importing the dump into an editor and manually editing out all the fields, not much I can thing of without setting up a script in your preferred language that can edit the sql queries to remove the columns and values. 

How did you create the dump?

Comment: I edited my question, dump is created with --data-only option. Any recommendation for editing tool?

Comment: I see... postgresql pg_dump format option looks interesting. I'll have a look at that. Apart from that, another way I thought of would be doing a Create table based on the columns you know exist and then dump that so that you have the definition there. If you want to take the editor approach, I would suggest sublime text. Using find and replace should provide you a quick way to manipulate the contents of the dump.

Comment: I think the best way is to write a script for this. It's messy to do migrations for columns that I need to delete in the end. 
Manual edit of dump is a bit risky, I need to delete all of the data in that column, not only column name. Now i need to learn how to write a script for this:) (ruby)

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to operate in steps:

1. Create an unlogged or temporary table that has all the columns.
2. `COPY` your file into that table.
3. Use `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ...` to insert the appropriate parts of the unlogged or temporary table.
4. Drop the unlogged table or terminate the session to delete the temporary table.

The alternative is to use tools like `awk` to preprocess your file and remove the extra columns.